# Hyperlink.add Anchor with .Cells instead of .Range

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have some code that doesn't seem to be working shown below

```
With Cells(emptyRow, 13)
     .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(emptyRow, 13), _
     Address:=EmailLinkTextBox.Value, TextToDisplay:="Link"
End With
```

and I believe it is due to the anchor because I found that the description for anchor stated it can be either a Range or Shape object.

Is this the issue, if so is there anyway to make it work?

Thank You

Comment: Thank you for your comment it pointed me in the right direction and resolved my issue. The code is simply now `.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(emptyRow, 13), Address:=EmailLinkTextBox.Value, TextToDisplay:="Link"`

Comment: I think I might have accidentally deleted the original comment, Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting the anchor to the address `.Cells(emptyRow, 13)` within a `With Cells(emptyRow, 13)` block (i.e. equivalent to `Cells(emptyRow, 13).Cells(emptyRow, 13)`, the anchor will be being placed in `Cells(2 * emptyRow - 1, 2 * 13 - 1)`.

You probably want to change the anchor to just be `Cells(emptyRow, 13)` - i.e. replace your code with:

```
With Cells(emptyRow, 13)
     .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(emptyRow, 13), _
     Address:=EmailLinkTextBox.Value, TextToDisplay:="Link"
End With
```

or

```
With Cells(emptyRow, 13)
     .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(1, 1), _
     Address:=EmailLinkTextBox.Value, TextToDisplay:="Link"
End With
```

Note:  A `Cell` is a `Range` object - it's just that it only has a 1 x 1 size.